# Как отправить HTML-письмо?

Tags: email, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Я совсем новичок! У меня возникла задача отправлять эл. письма, красиво оформленные, я создала нужный мне файл HTML в блокноте, а как его теперь в письмо добавить? Если в текст письма вставляю код, то приходит просто код. Видимо, нужно писать функцию на PHP? Пожалуйста, подскажите, как написать и куда вставлять.

Comment: Можно отправить функцией PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) (см. пример №4). А так зависит от почтового клиента — чем вы пользуетесь для отправки писем?

Comment: Яндекс и мэил. Спасибо за ответ, а где этот пример посмотреть?

Comment: Я перешла по вашей ссылке, к сожалелию, мне ничего не понятно. Может, есть способ подоступнее?

Comment: Яндекс и мэйл не дают возможности отправлять html-письма. Один из самых простых вариантов, это сделать и отправить html письмо через Outlook, вот инструкция: http://rightblog.ru/917

Comment: MasterAlex, спасибо. Я уже скачала и установила программу mozilla thunderbird. Но с ней тоже возникли проблемы - не удается правильно настроить параметры сервера, если есть возможность помочь, буду благодарна.